# Drupal Commerce Multiple Product Listing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am currently working on a project based on drupal + drupal commerce module.

I made a products node (Product Display) using the product reference and inline entity form - Multiple Values.

Now the problem is, I want to list products in a "div" rather than listing them through select box.

To be more clear:
It does list out multiple products, but shows only 1 product at a time. I have to select a product from the drop-down list.

As you can see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO8if.jpg

Please note: Table panel and bottle box are products.

What I want is:
All the products should be listed without the need of a drop-down select box selection.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have used only one node of type "product display" for two diferent products "Table Panel" and "Bottle Box"?
If you create one node for each product its easier do display them as a list.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, I wasn't doing it in the right way. I found out the way. I can make product displays and then render them as a VIEW. And style it accordingly. Again many thanks for your input, it really helped me to think, why am I doing this way.

Thanks nimbfire.